# Add all instance of a variable together in a PHP foreach loop?

Tags: php

I am trying to do something that's quite complex (for me anyway) and I've got a point which has stopped me in my tracks.

In this project, you enter the weight of a box, and the percentage of materials held in that box. So for example, a box may have 10% of wood, 40% of plastic, and 50% of paper. The weights of the materials are held in the database as they dont change. So the value of 1% of wood is held in the database, as 1% of plastic and paper.

The controller should then take the percentage of material given, and then multiply it by the 1% value held in the database.

So far, this is my code:

```
foreach($wastestream as $ws) { 
        $genweight = $ws['Materialtype']['1pc'] * $ws['Valuegiven']['percent'];
}
```

And this gives the following values:

```
10% Wood = 97.5
40% Plastic = 100.4
50% Paper = 40.3
```

The problem I now have is that I have to add all of these variables together. So essentially what I want to do after it pumps out the values is to add them all up together, so:

```
97.5 + 100.4 + 40.3 = 238.2
```

What should I do?

Cheers!

Comment: Maths has never been my strong point! But, according to GCSE's, I passed. Somehow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have misunderstood something, since it seems not complicated at all...

```
$total=0;
foreach($wastestream as $ws) { 
        $total += $ws['Materialtype']['1pc'] * $ws['Valuegiven']['percent'];
}
```

$total will hold the total value

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the values as they are created?

```
$totalweight = 0;
foreach($wastestream as $ws) { 
    $genweight = $ws['Materialtype']['1pc'] * $ws['Valuegiven']['percent'];
    $totalweight += $genweight;
}
```